# how to insert auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

If i've the following database

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `year` text,
  `event` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('2011', 'john');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('2011', 'dave');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('2010', 'hany');
```

My question is how to add `id` `auto_increment` so that it can be

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1, '2011', 'john');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (2, '2011', 'dave');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (3, '2010', 'hany');
```

I've tired this but failed

```
$q1 = "ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment";
mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error()." at row ".__LINE__);
```

and given me error `Incorrect table definition` so how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should add first the `COLUMN` then `INDEX` and then `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD COLUMN `id` int(3) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

OR 2 queries:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN `id` int (3) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY `id`(`id`), CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: lorga thanks a lot it, Works perfect that would really save a lot of time to me.